# Number of Hamilton paths in graphs

Tags: graphs, hamiltonian-path, backtracking

I am trying to find a fast algorithm that can compute the number of hamiltonian paths in an undirected graph. I saw [this](https://www.techiedelight.com/print-all-hamiltonian-path-present-in-a-graph/) on the web, but it sounds like this finds all hamiltonian paths starting from one specific vertex. (for example vertex '0' in this code)

One idea is to run the above algorithm for all of the vertices as a starting point and then half the number of total paths to get the answer (because each path has $2$ starting vertices and by this approach, we are computing each path twice). I was wondering if there is a straight algorithm with backtracking which is faster than what I just mentioned above.

Also,if m is the number of edges in our graph, for simplicity assume that $m \leq \frac{1}{2} C(n,2)$

Comment: Even detecting whether a graph has a single HP is an NP-hard problem, so no fast (subexponential-time) algorithms are known.

Comment: Yes, but I meant faster than what I suggested!

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to make it more precise about what you mean by "fast"?  What is the running time of the algorithm you listed?  How much faster does it have to be, to count as fast?  Subexponential time?  Exponential but with a lower exponent?  If this is a practical problem, how large will the graphs be, concretely?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65158319/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133060/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).